# laravel Redirect::intended() redirects to the full URL

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a custom Auth driver for Laravel 4 that needs to redirect back to whatever page triggered the authentication process. The driver drops the user out to a single sign-on service on a completely different domain, then back again once their service had signed the user in. All of that works fine right up until the first time the user is returned from the SSO server. I'm using a `return Redirect::intended();` statement to get back to where the user needs to be, but rather than accessing `http://www.some.dev/secret` and being redirected to the same, the user is being redirected to `http://www.some.dev/http://www.some.dev/secret` which, naturally, doesn't quite work properly. I chased down how Laravel stores the `REQUEST_URI` session variable, and it seems to pull the full URL. Not sure how other people don't end up redirected incorrectly, but I'm curious if anyone has faced this and if so, how you fixed it, whether it was a bad configuration file or tweaking the framework.

**eta**: in the 404 stack trace, Laravel says the `REQUEST_URI` value is set to `/http://www.some.dev/secret`. So it seems not to be an .htaccess goof.

**eta2**: tested my route two ways:

`Route::get('secret', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ExampleController@phpinfo'));`

and

`Route::get('/secret', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ExampleController@phpinfo'));`

No difference.

**eta3**: I'm just going to keep adding stuff. So this behavior only occurs when I log out of Eloquent (but not SSO), and even then only the first time I go to the page. So let's say the very first time, I'm not signed in to SSO or Eloquent. I sign on through SSO, which then logs me in internally through Eloquent. I get the wrong `REQUEST_URI`. I go back to the address bar, ditch the stuff behind `http://www.some.dev/` and type `secret` back in (browsing straight to `http://www.some.dev/secret`). I get to the page without any problem. On my page is a logout link that clears the Eloquent credentials. I also echoed `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` at the bottom of the page, and I see it's `/secret`. I click the logout button, which clears Eloquent credentials but keeps SSO credentials alive. I browse back to `/secret` and I see the same nonsense `REQUEST_URI`. Clear, enter `secret` again, and I'm fine. So it seems that when I'm re-validating my Eloquent credentials with `Auth::login` it's messing up my `REQUEST_URI`. Could that be because I'm bouncing credentials off a different domain, so the framework had to convert a relative URL into a static one?

Comment: Is there really a slash in front of `REDIRECT_URI`? That's most certainly a problem.

Comment: I guess there's two ways of looking at it: should it be `/[relative path]` or `[full path]`? I'd settle for either. I suspect Laravel intended for it to be `[full path]` because `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:61` returns `$this->request->fullUrl();`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the redirectBackTo URL that you're passing over to the SSO server in the first place is incorrect.